# Formatting time s:mm.00 in Excel (Office 2010) and graphing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time, cell-format

My son is a competitive swimmer. I would like to make a stacked bar chart using the various time standards for each stroke. The times are listed in `m:ss.00` format. I have several problems I need help with:

1. For times under one minute, sometimes I can't get the time to enter correctly into Excel; for example, I can enter `27.79` just fine, but if I try to enter `28.99`, it gets converted to `45:36.00`, unless I enter the leading zero, and I don't want the leading zero to show up on the chart. In order to consolidate all my questions, I'm tolerating the leading zero for now.
2. How can I create a bar or column chart with all the values listed in the same column, without the times being stacked? The time standards are associated with letter grades. I can get the letter grades to show in a separate column, but not within the same column. This may be the best I can do...
3. I'd like the minimum value to be something higher than zero. I've tried to change the axis minimum, but the time format is presenting a challenge. Several series have various times under a minute, and I'd like to REALLY stretch this out by changing the minimum value or inserting a break so that throughout the time year, times dropped (sometimes fractions of a second) can be added without crowding too much.
4. Lastly, I'd like to add prior season actual times as single scatter plots. It seems like I could easily do this in much earlier versions of Excel, back when I had more technical knowledge. I find these newer, highly automated versions very difficult to customize.

I put a copy of the file in my Dropbox, here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ih3067s86e3r0cg/Nat%20AG%20Mot%20Times%202013-2016.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to attack the first problem.  Enter the times in column **A** as *seconds* with the fractional part included.  Then in **B1** enter:

```
=A1/(24*3600)
```

and format **B1** as *Custom m:ss.00*:

[image]

Comment: While I definitely got something out of this lesson (I always appreciate the math!), I don't think this eliminates the leading zero.  Also, I can't figure out how this solution gets me ahead - it seems like it adds a couple of steps to get me back where I started.  If I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: Here's a partial answer for #3: Go to Chart Tools, Axes, Primary Horizontal Axes, More Primary Horizontal Axes Options, and from there I could adjust the minimum and maximum by trial and error to Min. 0.00031 and Max. to 0.00065.  I would prefer to know what these numbers actually represent, but finding the means to the end is more important.  How Excel is saving me so much time!  Not at all easier than dragging out a posterboard, some markers, and a ruler!

Comment: The numbers are fractions of a day.  Since a day is 86400 (24×60×60) seconds, 0.00031 represents 0.00031×86400=26.784 seconds, and 0.00065 represents 0.00065×86400=56.16 seconds.